# How to set format list (ordered,bullet) ,indent(in,out), text color, background text color in Quill using simple javascript

Tags: javascript, html, quill, rich-text-editor

I want to set the format of a list (ordered, bullet), indent(in, out), text color, background text color to the Quill text editor.
I used `this.quill.format('list',true)` this function to format list. But it set to bullet default. I can not set the number ordered list. I check the document shows the use

1. Orderlist => `{'list':'ordered'}`
2. Unordered => `{'list':'bullet'}`
3. Indent => `{'indent':'+1'}`
   like that.

I can't execute this command using javascript. it gives parameter error.

I am using https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/ this way to pass format.

What is the correct way of format for Quill?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using `ngx-quill` because of the `tag`. You can override the default Quill toolbar and create a custom toolbar. You just need to specify your customization inside the `<quill-editor> </quill-editor>` tag.

Try to add this code between `<quill-editor> </quill-editor>`:

```
 <div quill-editor-toolbar>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-bold" ngbPopover="Bold" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-italic" ngbPopover="Italic" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-underline" ngbPopover="Underline" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-strike" ngbPopover="Strikethrough" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-blockquote" ngbPopover="Blockquote" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-code-block" ngbPopover="Code block" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-list" value="ordered" ngbPopover="Ordered list" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet" ngbPopover="Bulleted list" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-script" value="sub" ngbPopover="Subscript" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-script" value="super" ngbPopover="Superscript" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-indent" value="-1" ngbPopover="Indent -1" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-indent" value="+1" ngbPopover="Indent +1" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl" ngbPopover="Text direction" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats" ngbPopover="Font size" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">
                      <select class="ql-size">
                        <option value="small"></option>
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="large"></option>
                        <option value="huge"></option>
                      </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats" ngbPopover="Text color" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">
                      <select class="ql-color">
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="#e60000"></option>
                        <option value="#ff9900"></option>
                        <option value="#ffff00"></option>
                        <option value="#008a00"></option>
                        <option value="#0066cc"></option>
                        <option value="#9933ff"></option>
                        <option value="#ffffff"></option>
                        <option value="#facccc"></option>
                        <option value="#ffebcc"></option>
                        <option value="#ffffcc"></option>
                        <option value="#cce8cc"></option>
                        <option value="#cce0f5"></option>
                        <option value="#ebd6ff"></option>
                        <option value="#bbbbbb"></option>
                        <option value="#f06666"></option>
                        <option value="#ffc266"></option>
                        <option value="#ffff66"></option>
                        <option value="#66b966"></option>
                        <option value="#66a3e0"></option>
                        <option value="#c285ff"></option>
                        <option value="#888888"></option>
                        <option value="#a10000"></option>
                        <option value="#b26b00"></option>
                        <option value="#b2b200"></option>
                        <option value="#006100"></option>
                        <option value="#0047b2"></option>
                        <option value="#6b24b2"></option>
                        <option value="#444444"></option>
                        <option value="#5c0000"></option>
                        <option value="#663d00"></option>
                        <option value="#666600"></option>
                        <option value="#003700"></option>
                        <option value="#002966"></option>
                        <option value="#3d1466"></option>
                      </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats" ngbPopover="Background color" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">

                      <select class="ql-background">
                        <option value="#000000"></option>
                        <option value="#e60000"></option>
                        <option value="#ff9900"></option>
                        <option value="#ffff00"></option>
                        <option value="#008a00"></option>
                        <option value="#0066cc"></option>
                        <option value="#9933ff"></option>
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="#facccc"></option>
                        <option value="#ffebcc"></option>
                        <option value="#ffffcc"></option>
                        <option value="#cce8cc"></option>
                        <option value="#cce0f5"></option>
                        <option value="#ebd6ff"></option>
                        <option value="#bbbbbb"></option>
                        <option value="#f06666"></option>
                        <option value="#ffc266"></option>
                        <option value="#ffff66"></option>
                        <option value="#66b966"></option>
                        <option value="#66a3e0"></option>
                        <option value="#c285ff"></option>
                        <option value="#888888"></option>
                        <option value="#a10000"></option>
                        <option value="#b26b00"></option>
                        <option value="#b2b200"></option>
                        <option value="#006100"></option>
                        <option value="#0047b2"></option>
                        <option value="#6b24b2"></option>
                        <option value="#444444"></option>
                        <option value="#5c0000"></option>
                        <option value="#663d00"></option>
                        <option value="#666600"></option>
                        <option value="#003700"></option>
                        <option value="#002966"></option>
                        <option value="#3d1466"></option>
                      </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats"  ngbPopover="Font" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">
                      <select class="ql-font">
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="serif"></option>
                        <option value="monospace"></option>
                      </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats" ngbPopover="Alignment" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave">
                      <select class="ql-align">
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="center"></option>
                        <option value="justify"></option>
                        <option value="right"></option>
                      </select>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-clean" ngbPopover="Clear all formatting" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ql-formats">
                      <button class="ql-link" ngbPopover="Link" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-image" ngbPopover="Image" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                      <button class="ql-video" ngbPopover="Video" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"></button>
                    </span>

</div>
```

This is my customization, and includes everything that the default Quill toolbar include, but includes some extra things because of the plugins that I used. Also, it has the tooltips for each section of the toolbar. You can modified it how you need it, but this customization includes both the ordered and unordered lists, as well as indents.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for your input. I want to do with simple javascript.  @Nenad Milosavljevic

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format a line in Quill, you should be using [`quill.formatLine()`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#formatline).

Rather then use `true` for the value of your list, you can also specify `ordered`. So given this document:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

You can set the second line to be an ordered list like this:

```js
quill.formatLine(4, 'list', 'ordered');
```

Where `4` is the start of the `bar` line (because as a raw string, the above looks like `foo\nbar\nbaz`).

Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/alecgibson/pen/PoWLryr)